# Shapefile topo projections not displaying all data using geopandas, geoplot, and matplotlib

Tags: python, geopandas, python-3

I'm currently trying to display topographic map data for an area. Although the data that is displayed is showing up correctly, there are visible chunks missing from the final projection. I don't have an "expected output", but from the image below it is fairly easy to tell that chunks are missing from the topographic map. I have repeated this with different areas and it is producing the same missing chunks. For less dense maps, such as the default US data from geopandas, I have had no issue displaying all of the data.

```
import geoplot as gplt
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


map = gpd.read_file(r"<shapefile-location>\Elev_Contour.shp")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
map.plot(ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Example Outputs:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSE8y.png),
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxpgP.png)

Shapefile in question:
[(I get it's not the most secure method, but here's a Google Drive link)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f6L_i_Y12zsYdx_6tJNdUF-8Y0AmDL5x/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You have GeoPandas in your title list twice. Did you mean to include Pandas?

Comment: I meant to say "geoplot", sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That link only has a .shp file, not the rest of the SHP file extensions.